# can we raise a PR in github through jenkins

Tags: github, jenkins, pull-request

there is a requirement to automate the PR via jenkins,when changes done in github repo.the jenkins should automatically raise pull request.
is it possible automate .plz help me with this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Gitcli](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_pr_create) for this. This can be executed through Jenkins using a shell executor.

Answer (score 0):

if you could explain the requirement in more detail, it would be more helpful.

One way I could think of raising a PR on GitHub using Jenkins is by using GitHub's API.

- GitHub has an [API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/pulls) to work with pull requests. I believe you would specifically need the "[Create a pull request](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/pulls/pulls#create-a-pull-request)" API.
- Jenkins has a plugin - "[HTTP Request](https://plugins.jenkins.io/http_request/)" to make HTTP requests.
- In your Jenkins pipeline, create a job that makes a POST request to the `/repos/{owner}/{repo}/pulls` endpoint. You can declare the status as success/failure based on the response status code.